# How to add custom key shortcut for opening markdown preview in side panel in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Using `Ctrl+K V` we can open markdown preview in side panel, but my requirement is different.

I want to add custom keyboard shortcut to open markdown preview for markdown file which is present my hard disc at any specific location.

Suppose I have `D:\testData\test.md` file. Now if I press any specific key (ex. ctrl+e) in vs code then preview of `test.md` should get displayed at right side panel in vs code.

Comment: use the extension `multi-command`, and create a sequence of commands to open the file, wait a bit, and then show preview of md file, use `HTML Related File` to open a file using arguments

Comment: @rioV8 note: VS Code 1.77 has `"runCommands"`.

Comment: @starball Yes but it can't add a wait in between commands (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by editing **Keyboard Shortcuts** in vs code

goto:
**Files > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**

search for "ctrl+k v"

you will see command: "*Markdown: Open Preview to the Side*"

here you can edit the **Keybinding** to whatever you like.

images for reference:

[keyboard shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS3cB.png)

[search for correct shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWc8p.png)

[change the Keybinding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmqk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a keybinding to do this with an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  For example, with this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+e",          // whatever keybinding you want 
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "run": [
      "$${",
        "const uri = vscode.Uri.file('C:\\\\Users\\\\Mark\\\\folder-operations\\\\CHANGELOG.md');",
        "vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown.showPreviewToSide', uri);",
      "}$$",
    ],
    "runWhen": "onceOnNoMatches",
  }
}
```

Note that the backslashes need to appear as `\\\\` - that represents each backslash being double-escaped.

The only requirements are that an editor be focused and that your cursor is not at a "word" so there is no match (the extension is primarily designed to make find/searches easy and powerful so it would otherwise create the find).  On an empty line or after punctuation for example.

[image: open markdown preview demo]